# I have a following code that calls the api and displays the API response without refreshing the page. It does not seem to work as of now :(

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, rest

Can any one please check what might be the issue. I have added my API key as well...I have a following code that calls the api and displays the API response without refreshing the page. It does not seem to work as of now :(

I am adding it via a short code in the WordPress page. Been working to get this done right but cant seem to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax form submit without reloading page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
form {
text-align: center;
padding: 26px;
margin: 11px;
}
div {
    padding: 15px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is the simple form using Ajax</h1>
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#name').val();
        
            $.ajax({

              URL: "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions",

              type: "POST", 

              data: JSON.stringify({

                    "prompt": "name",

                    "max_tokens": 10,

                    "temperature": 0.7,

                    "top_p": 1.0

}),

            headers: {

                    'Authorization': 'Bearer sk-MY API KEY',

                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

},

            success: function(response) {

                    console.log(response);
                    $("#completion").html(response.choices[0].text);

}

});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: completion div is missing

Comment: Looking at the browser devtools' console and network tabs can help troubleshoot this kind of problem.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Object.success (?preview_id=1112&preview_nonce=0a372fd0d1&preview=true:216:44)
    at fire (jquery-3.x-git.js:3558:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.x-git.js:3688:7)
    at done (jquery-3.x-git.js:9900:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.x-git.js:10161:9)


Here is the error from console

Comment: I figured the issue was with      $("#completion").html(response.choices[0].text);

when i remove it I still don't see the API response. SO the issue is in the code definately.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `<script>` tags in the header